# How to use the random function in cplex

Tags: cplex

How can I generate a new random number each time I run it with the random function in the Cplex because it only generates a random number for me and doesn't change anything every time I run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OPL you may use the rand function

```
int v;

execute
{
  v=(new Date().getMilliseconds());
}

int sr=srand(v); // OPL random seed

execute
 {
 sr;
 writeln("OPL random seed=",sr);
 writeln(Opl.rand(10));
 }

 int inputData[i in 1..10]=rand(10);

execute
{
  writeln(inputData);
}

int inputData2[i in 1..50]=50+rand(51);

execute
{
  writeln(inputData2);
}
```

will give different results each time

More in https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5557&MID=87124&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer

Comment: Thank you. The only question I have is, can we use this randomly generated data as input data?

Comment: Sure , I ll give you an example

Comment: Thank you Mr Fleischer.

Comment: If we want to define a range, for example, between 50 and 100, that gives us random numbers between these ranges, please say me the syntax.

Comment: done but try to add new questions in new threads so that other users can benefit from previous answers please

Comment: Sure , Thank you.